# Add a linked image to html body with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a linked image with JavaScript to the HTML body. The image is displayed, but it's not opening any link (the `onclick` event is not triggered).

The reason I'm not just adding the `href` attribute is, because I want to show different linked images for different scenarios.

**My HTML code**:

```
<div id="mypic">
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wr9k0zwcxg0315/you%27re_invited.jpg?dl=1"
         align="middle">
</div>
```

**My JavaScript code**:

```
var lang="en";
var survey = document.createElement('survey');
survey.href="http://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/2654176/case-closed-survey";
var image = document.getElementById('mypic').getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var b = survey.appendChild(image);
document.getElementById('mypic').appendChild(survey);
```

Comment: You use survey inside `.createElement()` which is not valid. Check my answer for more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38246327/6313073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your code you say**:

```
var survey = document.createElement('survey');
```

- Inside the `.createElement()` method you have to insert a `node`. You face a problem, because `survey` is not a valid `node` and will no be considered as one in any of the HTML versions released to date.
- To fix it, insert an `anchor node` inside `.createElement()`.

**Your code should be**:

```
var survey = document.createElement('a');
```

---

**Notes**:

- Adding the `href` attribute is a no brainer. That's what prompts the web browser to navigate to the given link.
- In order to display a different image based on different scenarios, you just have to replace the given link with some other.

For example:

```
var link = ((scenario 1) ? "..." : ((scenario 2) ? "..." : "..."));
survey.href = link;
```

Comment: Glad to help @freckles.karin!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a mystery element "survey" here -

```
var survey = document.createElement('survey');
```

You need to make it an anchor -

```
var survey = document.createElement('a');
```